# SvelteKit Server-Side Rewrites

Tags: svelte, vercel, sveltekit

I'm looking for a solution to rewrite requests server-side (preserving the request url but responding with the page contents of another route) with SvelteKit hosted on Vercel.

Vercel's middleware is not an option according to [their docs](https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks/sveltekit#server-side-rendering).

SvelteKit's [handle server hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handle) seems like a logical option but the only recommendations I can find are either redirects which don't preserve the URL or manually proxying the request with fetch which could cause caching and security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try a dynamic route to capture the url you're trying to rewrite, then dynamically render whatever page component you're trying to rewrite to with the method describe in this answer:

[How can I get previous route matches in a SvelteKit route matcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77627121/how-can-i-get-previous-route-matches-in-a-sveltekit-route-matcher/77762290#77762290)