# How can I get previous route matches in a SvelteKit route matcher?

Tags: sveltekit

I'm trying to set up my site for internationalized urls so I can match on urls like
`/en/privacy` and `/es/privacidad`.  But a url like `/en/privacidad` should be a 404

I've set up the folder structure like

```
routes
  [lang=lang]
    [route1=route1]
```

But I can't figure out how to get the current language in the `route1` route matcher.

Getting it from the page store doesn't work since it's outside component context. I'm also not sure how to get the full url since the route matchers run on both server and client.

How do I get previous route matches or the full url in a route matcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself by not trying to match everything in the route matcher, and handling some of it in the load components.

So with a `urls.json` file to define what each possible route1 route is:

```
{
  "en": {
    "route1": {
      "privacy": "privacy",
      "search": "search"
    }
  },
  "es": {
    "route1": {
      "privacy": "privacidad",
      "search": "buscar"
    }
  }
}
```

In the `params/route1.ts` then make sure the route matches *any* of the languages:

```
import type { ParamMatcher } from "@sveltejs/kit"
import urls from '$lib/urls.json';
import { findMatchingValues } from "$lib/findMatchingValues";

export const match = (function match(param) {
  const matches = findMatchingValues<string>(urls, "*.route1.*");
  return matches.includes(param);
}) satisfies ParamMatcher;
```

And in the `routes/[lang=lang]/[route1=route1]/+page.ts` file, find which page matched and return it for data:

```
import type { PageLoad } from './$types'
import urls from '$lib/urls.json';
import type { LocaleCode } from '$lib/poly-i18n/locales';
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const load: PageLoad = async ({ params, parent, data }) => {
  const lang = params.lang as LocaleCode;
  const route1 = params.route1.toLowerCase();
  const { t } = await parent();

  const route1Urls: Record<string, string> = urls[lang].route1;
  const matched = Object.keys(route1Urls).find(key => route1Urls[key] === route1);

  if (!matched) {
    throw error(404, 'Page + ' + t('common.notFound', { values: { route: route1 ?? '' } }));
  }

  return {
    matched,
    ...data
  }
}
```

And finally in `routes/[lang=lang]/[route1=route1]/+page.svelte` dynamically render the matching component

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Privacy from '$pages/privacy/+page.svelte';
    import Search from '$pages/search/+page.svelte';
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

    export let data;

    let matched: string;
    let component: ConstructorOfATypedSvelteComponent | undefined = undefined;

    $: {
        matched = data.matched;

        switch (matched) {
            case 'search':
                component = Search;
                break;
            case 'privacy':
                component = Privacy;
                break;
        }

        if (!component) {
            if (browser) {
                goto(`/${data.lang}/`);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

{#if component}
    <svelte:component this={component} {data} />
{/if}
```